# What type of hoops do I have to jump through to launch high power rockets?

Tags: faa-regulations

If I want to launch high power rockets NOT at a NAR or TRA sanctioned launch, assuming I am properly certified, what do I need to do?  I looked in the FAR|AIM, but I couldn't find anything on rockets, but I think the rocketry section has been omitted from the PPT FAR|AIM.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The FAR section that you are looking for is available on the ecfr website:

[PART 101—MOORED BALLOONS, KITES, AMATEUR ROCKETS AND UNMANNED FREE BALLOONS](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr&rgn=div5&view=text&node=14:2.0.1.3.15&idno=14)

More specifically, it is [Subpart C— Amateur Rockets](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr&rgn=div5&view=text&node=14:2.0.1.3.15&idno=14#14:2.0.1.3.15.3)

The main regulations that apply are (see the above link for the full text of the regulations):

> **§101.23   General operating limitations.**
>
> (a) You must operate an amateur rocket in such a manner that it:
>
> (1) Is launched on a suborbital trajectory;
>
> (2) When launched, must not cross into the territory of a foreign
>   country unless an agreement is in place between the United States and
>   the country of concern;
>
> (3) Is unmanned; and
>
> (4) Does not create a hazard to persons, property, or other aircraft.
>
> (b) The FAA may specify additional operating limitations necessary to
>   ensure that air traffic is not adversely affected, and public safety
>   is not jeopardized.
>
> **§101.25   Operating limitations for Class 2-High Power Rockets and Class 3-Advanced High Power Rockets.**
>
> When operating Class 2-High Power Rockets or Class 3-Advanced High
>   Power Rockets, you must comply with the General Operating Limitations
>   of §101.23. In addition, you must not operate Class 2-High Power
>   Rockets or Class 3-Advanced High Power Rockets—
>
> (a) At any altitude where clouds or obscuring phenomena of more than
>   five-tenths coverage prevails;
>
> (b) At any altitude where the horizontal visibility is less than five
>   miles;
>
> (c) Into any cloud;
>
> (d) Between sunset and sunrise without prior authorization from the
>   FAA;
>
> (e) Within 9.26 kilometers (5 nautical miles) of any airport boundary
>   without prior authorization from the FAA;
>
> (f) In controlled airspace without prior authorization from the FAA;
>
> (g) Unless you observe the greater of the following separation
>   distances from any person or property that is not associated with the
>   operations:
>
> (1) Not less than one-quarter the maximum expected altitude;
>
> (2) 457 meters (1,500 ft.);
>
> (h) Unless a person at least eighteen years old is present, is charged
>   with ensuring the safety of the operation, and has final approval
>   authority for initiating high-power rocket flight; and
>
> (i) Unless reasonable precautions are provided to report and control a
>   fire caused by rocket activities.
>
> **§101.27   ATC notification for all launches.**
>
> No person may operate an unmanned rocket other than a Class 1—Model
>   Rocket unless that person gives the following information to the FAA
>   ATC facility nearest to the place of intended operation no less than
>   24 hours before and no more than three days before beginning the
>   operation:
>
> ...
>
> **§101.29   Information requirements.**.
>
> ...